# mysql relational table partitioning

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, bigdata

Hellow to all of you guys.
I have a three-table like below:

1-The movie table:

```
+----+-------------+
| id | movie_name  |
+----+-------------+
```

2-The actor table:

```
+----+-------------+
| id | actor_name  |
+----+-------------+
```

3-The movie_actor table:

```
+----------+-------------+
| movie_id | actor_id    |
+----------+-------------+
```

ok, I realize that if I have 20 million movies inside movie table and each movie have 20 actors then The movie_actor table should have 400 million rows and query on this large table will be slow even if I use the index on movie_id and actor id because after a long time the rows in movie_actor will be very very large like 1billion and more.
then I read about partitioning. but partitioning the movie_actor is a question for me. I want basically two queries on this table:

> to get all movies that one actor is acting on:

1-

```
`select movie_id from movie_actor where actor_id = 102547;`
```

> to get all actors that acting in a movie:
> 2-

```
`select actor_id from movie_actor where movie_id = 200145364;`
```

but I don't know have and on which column and on what condition I should partition this database to does not affect my queries. Any Body can help me to do this? This is very important to me.this is a test that I create for myself to simulate real-world applications. I know any application about movies does not have 20 million movies. Anybody can help me I will be great full?

Comment: you will have more helpfull answers if you post your question on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: every row has 16 bytes to handle 8 for each id(lets say it is bigint), so even if you have 2500 millions rows, it will only take few staep ti get your wanted ids.  you can generate such a table automatically with every amounzt if row you want anfd test ist Big tables withg öots of columns are a problem, and slow hardware. and if yu need infrmation from ivie ir actor mysql will find it also quick. try it

Comment: bbaird covered a lot of good stuff. I agree with _not_ partitioning. I want to add that, especially with 400M rows, you should follow the tips here: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Comment: @N69S - Is serverfault necessarily better than dba.stackexchange?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to partition.  If you are using InnoDB as your engine and you choose `(movie_id, actor_id)` as your primary key, the rows will be arranged (generally, more on that later) according to `movie_id` and very easy for the database to locate.

However, the second search condition based on `actor_id` would have to scan the whole table (which is narrow, not that big of a deal) but if someone doesn't want to wait 1.5 seconds you can create a secondary index on `(actor_id, movie_id)`.  In this case, the index will be an exact copy of the table but organized according to `actor_id`.  So no matter the direction, the database engine will be able to locate the required records quickly.

Even for databases that store things in heaps, the leaves of the B-Tree index are (generally, more on that later) in order according to the key value to make finding the appropriate page faster.

Over time, all tables/indexes will fragment.  Surprisingly, this doesn't anyways affect performance as much as you'd think, but if you did see degradation you could always rebuild the tables/indexes.  A commercial database can do that online, "free" will require you to take the database offline long enough to rebuild the table.  Smaller tables/indexes take less time, naturally.

Comment: Partitioning basically makes one large table into a smaller table, each table with it's own copy of indexes, etc.  There's more overhead and it will not always result in better performance.

Comment: "each with its own copy of indexes"  -- More specifically, those indexes are _only_ for the rows in the partition, not the entire table.